# HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer() on timed out connection does not throw IOException

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I am facing quite an unusual situation. 
I have two Jboss (7.1) instances which communicate via HTTP.
Instance A opens an HTTP connection to instance B and sends some data to be processed. The connection has timeout set, so after N seconds if no response is read it throws SocketTimeoutEception. Some cleanup is performed and the connection is closed.
Instance B has a servlet, listening for such http requests and when one is received some computation is done. After that the response is populated and returned to the client.

The problem is that if the computation takes too much time, the client (A) will close the connection due to the time out, but server (B) will proceed as normal and will try to send the response after some time. I want to be able to detect that the connection is closed and do some house keeping, however I can't seem to be able to do that.

I have tried calling HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer(), but no exception is thrown. I have also explicitly set in the http request "Connection: close" to avoid persistent connection, but this had no effect. The http servlet resonse is processed as normal and disappears in the void without any exception. I do not know what I am doing wrong, I've read other questions on this site like:

[Java's HttpServletResponse doesn't have isClientConnected method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606366/javas-httpservletresponse-doesnt-have-isclientconnected-method)

[Tomcat - Servlet response blocking - problems with flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446483/tomcat-servlet-response-blocking-problems-with-flush)

but they do not work in my case.

I think there might be something specific to the jboss servlet container, which causes to ignore or buffer the response, or perhaps the http connection is reused despite my efforts to close it from the client (A). I'd be happy if you could provide some pointers to where to look for the problem. I have spend several days on this and no relevant progress was made, so I need to resolve this urgently.

Here is the relevant code:

**Client code (server A):**

```
    private static int postContent(URL destination, String fileName, InputStream content)
    throws IOException, CRPostException
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        //Create the connection object
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)destination.openConnection();

        // Prepare the HTTP headers
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "zip");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");//Try to make it non-persistent

        //Timouts
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);//20 sec timout
        connection.setReadTimeout(20000);//20 sec read timeout

        // Connect to the remote system
        connection.connect();

        try
        {
            //Write something to the output stream
            writeContent(connection, fileName, content);

            //Handle response from server
            return handleResponse(connection);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.getInputStream().close();//Try to explicitly close the connection
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                connection.disconnect();//Close the connection??
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.warning("Failed to disconnect the HTTP connection");
            }
        }
    }

private static int handleResponse(HttpURLConnection connection)
    throws IOException, CRPostException
    {
        String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();//Where it blocks until server returns the response 
        int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            logger.debug("HTTP status code OK");
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

            try
            {
                if (in != null)
                {
                    //Read the result, parse it and return it
                    ....
                }
            }
            catch (JAXBException e)
            {
            }
        }// if

        //return error state
        return STATE_REJECTED;
    }//handleResponse()
```

**Server code (Server B):**

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String crXML = null;
    MediaType mediaType = null;
    Object result;

    // Get the media type of the received CR XML
    try
    {
        mediaType = getMediaType(request);
        crXML = loadDatatoString(mediaType, request);
        result = apply(crXML);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Application of uploaded data has failed");

        //Return response that error has occured
        ....

        return;
    }

    // Finally prepare the OK response
    buildStatusResponse(response, result);

    // Try to detect that the connection is broken
    // and the resonse never got to the client
    // and do some housekeeping if so
    try
    {
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
    catch (Throwable thr)
    {
        // Exception is never thrown !!!
        // I expect to get an IO exception if the connection has timed out on the client
        // but this never happens
        thr.printStackTrace();
    }
}// doPost(..)

public static void buildStatusResponse(HttpServletResponse responseArg, Object result)
{
    responseArg.setHeader("Connection", "close");//Try to set non persistent connection on the response too - no effect

    responseArg.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    // write response object
    ByteArrayOutputStream respBinaryOut = null;
    try
    {
        respBinaryOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter respWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(respBinaryOut, "UTF-8");
        JAXBTools.marshalStatusResponse(result, respWriter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Failed to write the response object", e);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        responseArg.setContentType(ICRConstants.HTTP_CONTENTTYPE_XML_UTF8);
        responseArg.getOutputStream().write(respBinaryOut.toByteArray());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.error("Failed to write response object in the HTTP response body!", e);
    }
}//buildStatusResponse()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into HTTP connection pooling at the client end. The physical connection isn't really closed, it is returned to a pool for possible later reuse. If it is idle for some timeout it is closed and removed from the pool. So at the moment the server flushBuffer() happened the connection was still alive.

OR

The data being flushed was small enough to fit into the socket send buffer at the sender, so the underlying write returned immediately and successfully, and the disconnect was only discovered later, asynchronously, by TCP.

Comment: There seems to be some buffering indeed on server side. the HttpServletResponse buffer size is reported to be 8192 bytes. My response was small - ~300 bytes, therefore I made a big byte array - 18000 bytes instead and tried to flush it instead. Now I get: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error. Seems your second proposal is correct. Any idea if I can configure the buffer size for the servlet response somehow?