# Spring MVC HTTP disconnect notification

Tags: http, spring-mvc

We are using REST infrastructure of Spring MVC over Tomcat 7.
We have requests that may last couple of seconds.
Do we have a way to get notified when the client of the HTTP request was disconnected and not listening to the response anymore?

Comment: From this ticket, it seems that you cannot do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606366/javas-httpservletresponse-doesnt-have-isclientconnected-method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any javascript component to make REST request? grid or dropdown?

Possibly you need to check response code from the call. If you get response code, it means client has disconnected.